# Gradle: how can I use dynamic properties on multiple tasks to fail a build?

Tags: java, svn, gradle

One of my build tasks pulls information on the current SVN branch. On builds from a tag I  want to be more strict and fail the build when e.g., a link checker finds dead links for the online help files. On regular builds from branches or trunk this should not break the build.

I have the following code, where the mentioned Perl script creates a properties file:

```
task generateSvnInfo(type: Exec) {
    outputs.files "generated/svninfo"
    executable "perl"
    args "..."
}

Properties buildProps = new Properties()

task svninfo() {
    inputs.files generateSvnInfo.outputs.files
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    buildProps.load(new FileInputStream(inputs.files.getSingleFile()))
}
```

Now my other targets depend on `svninfo` (and the fact that it populates `buildProps`).

```
task checkHelpLinks(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn "svninfo"
    executable "perl"
    args "..."
}
```

This will always fail if it finds dead help links. As far as I understand it, `ignoreExitValue` is `false` by default. To set it to `true` on non-tag builds, I can add this to the `checkHelpLinks` task:

```
ignoreExitValue = true
doLast {
    ignoreExitValue = buildProps.FROM_TAG == "false"
}
```

This works, but I have four or five of these check tasks and would like to not duplicate that code around. So I tried

```
tasks.grep(~ /^check.+/).each { task ->
    task.ignoreExitValue = true
    task.doLast {
        task.ignoreExitValue = buildProps.FROM_TAG == "false"
    }
}
```

This code does not seem to get executed. I thought that may be because I compare the Task object to a String in `grep`, but using

```
tasks.grep(it.name =~ /^check.+/).each { task ->
```

gets me a build script error ("Could not find property 'it' on root project 'foo'.)

How can I add my tag check to all check tasks?

Is there a better way to load the properties from a file that is created as part of the build process?

Is there a SVN plugin that would do the work for me?

Comment: Ok, I used the wrong braces on grep, `tasks.grep {it.name =~ /^check.+/}.each { task ->` works.

Comment: `buildProps.load` has to be wrapped with `doLast { ... }`. Otherwise the properties file will get loaded when the `svninfo` task gets *configured*, which is before any task has been executed.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It only worked earlier because the file was still around from a previous build.

Comment: To configure a subset of tasks, use sth. like `tasks.withType(Exec) { ... }` or `tasks.matching { it.name.startsWith("check") }.all { ... }`.